# get path of python binary that's executing the script

Tags: python, pylons, virtualenv

I have a Pylons controller (irrelevant but explains why I have this need) say `starter.py` that starts another process using:

```
retcode = subprocess.call(('python','/path/to/myScript.py'))
```

now since the app runs in a virtual env `python` is not the right binary to call since it has no access to site-packages installed in my virtual env.

It should be instead:

```
retcode = subprocess.call(('path/to/virtual/env/bin/python','/path/to/myScript.py'))
```

and `path/to/virtual/env/bin/python` is the same that is running `starter.py`.

Any chance to not set this path (say, in a .ini file) and retrieve it?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The path is available in [`sys.executable`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.executable).

Comment: The fastest answer ever, I'll accept when I'll be allowed to. Thanks

Comment: I've found one edge case where this isn't true -- the built-in Python in Sublime Text 3, for which sys.executable is simply `python3`

Comment: @PaulBissex: For embeded interpeters, there might not even exist a standalone Python binary, so there's not much you can do for these cases.  In general, it's probably preferable to try and run Python code within the current interpreter instead of forking to a sub-interpreter.

Comment: @SvenMarnach What if the file is self-executing? Let's say `myScript.py` has been compiled to `myScript.exe` ?

Comment: @TSR I've never done that (I don't use Windows), so I can't tell for sure.  However, the linked documentation indicates that `sys.executable` will be either `None` or an empty string in that case.

Comment: In my case ```which python3``` worked in macOS command line.